# JQuery Button Not Clickable Second Time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

I have used Youtube iframe api to play youtube video on button click.
Html code gets replaced with youtube iframe video code on button click.
When video is ended the previous html code gets replaced.
But some how the button clicks are not working second time.
Please Help !

This is my Code for HTML and JQuery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('.play_button').click(function(e){
      var html_sidebar = jQuery(this).closest(".sidebar-container2").html();
      var player;
      e.preventDefault();
          player = new YT.Player('video-play', {
           height: '345px',
             width: '100%',
             videoId: '7o0Nkfdp2s4',
             events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }      
          });

      

      // autoplay video
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
          event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // when video ends
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
          if(event.data === 0) {
           jQuery('#tertiary1').html(html_sidebar);
          }
      }
     });
  
    jQuery('#watch-video').click(function (e) {
        var html_sidebar = jQuery(this).closest(".sidebar-container2").html();
        var player;
        e.preventDefault();
        player = new YT.Player('video-play', {
            height: '345px',
            width: '100%',
            videoId: '7o0Nkfdp2s4',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });



        // autoplay video
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // when video ends
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data === 0) {
                jQuery('#tertiary1').html(html_sidebar);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div role="complementary" class="sidebar-container2" id="tertiary1">
    <div id="video-play" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-last widget-odd widget_video">
        <div class="textwidget">
            <div class="video_container">
                <span class="play_button"></span>
                <div class="video-text">
                    <h3>Delivering Change Foundation</h3>
                    <p>DCF is an independent organization that partners with governments and communities to accomplish nation transformation.</p>
                    <p><a id="watch-video" class="yellow_arrow">Watch the video
    </a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

What can I do ? I am new to jquery
tried to find solution but no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the original html markup is being altered.

The event handler is bound to initial `#watch-video` which gets replaced and is added again, so the events are lost.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#watch-video',function(){

});
```

You can use a static parent instead of `jQuery(document)`, to delegate this event which in your case is:

```
jQuery('#tertiary1').on('click','#watch-video',function(){

});
```

**Update**:

If you have multiple button triggers, use a combined selector,

```
jQuery('#tertiary1').on('click','#watch-video,.play_button',function(){

})
```

Comment: See the updated code, you can use a single click handler instead of two separate ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [event delegation method](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), replace your selector code with below code and try.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#watch-video', function (e) {
```